# How parser's buffer works? Matching the regex

Tags: java, regex

One of my students have a task to do which part is to check if there is a regex matching string inside of a file.
The trick is that his teacher has forbidden reading whole file at once then parse it. Instead he said that he supposed to use buffer. **The problem is that you never know how much of input you suppose to read from the file: there might be a matching sequence if you read just one character more from the file.**

So the teacher wrote(translated):
Use technique known from parsers:

1. rewrite second half of the buffer to the first part of buffer
2. read next part of file to the second half
3. check if whole buffer contains the matching sequence

So how it suppose to be done(idea)? In my opinion it does not solve the problem stated above and it is pretty stupid and wasteful.

Comment: Can the student use an external library? I have just what he needs...

Comment: Yes he does. I would just use BufferedReader and read line by line and process every line but still regex can contain "\\n",

Comment: So let me get this straight, this is a student of yours who has another teacher and you can't communicate directly with the teacher? NB the technique quoted by this alleged other teacher is unknown to parsing theory.

Answer (score 2):

A `Matcher` does use an internal buffer of some kind, certainly. But if you look at the prototype to build a `Matcher`, you see that the only thing it takes as an argument is a simple [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), which has only three operations:

- knowing its length,
- getting one character at a given offset,
- getting a subsequence (another `CharSequence`).

When reading from a file, one possibility is to map the *whole* file using `FileChannel.map()`, then use an appropriate `CharsetDecoder` to read into a `CharBuffer` (which implements `CharSequence`). Or do that in chunks...

... Or use yours truly's crazy idea: [this](https://github.com/fge/largetext)! I have tested it on 800+ MiB files and it works...

Answer (score 1):

What your teacher is saying:

- The regex will never need to match anything longer than half the length of the buffer.
- The match could lie on a buffer boundary, hence you need to shift:

That seems realistic.

A BufferedReader reading line wise seems not entirely fitting. Maybe you might consider a byte array, BufferedInputStream.

Comment: The problem with byte arrays is that if you are not careful in your decoding process, you can stumble upon a "frontier" (ie, the last byte of the array is the first byte of a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence which has no meaning by itself). Believe me, I've tested it all ;)

Comment: @fge yes I almost mentioned it myself as I am a UTF-8 afficionado. On the other hand, the implementation is straightforward, maybe some extra frills for UTF-8. Whereas your solution - which I personally have used (so +1 for ye) - is more challenging and maybe does not mirror the task's intention as explained by the teacher.

Comment: Well, I find the teacher's exercise a little pointless given what `Pattern`'s `.matcher()` expects... Or maybe the student is developing _his own_ regex engine but that would sound a little extreme. Maybe the teacher hasn't read the javadoc of `Matcher` carefully enough ;)

Comment: @fge, CharSequence is used way too little in APIs, so I enjoy seeing such a solution, especially if using a file channel. I still gave my answer after reading yours, as I think it less work (for school).